# Updating payment hold on bill in closed period throws error

Tags: netsuite

We have a vendor bill in closed period, which as ‘Allow non-GL transactions’ checked. When I go in and take off the payment hold on a vendor bill, it throws the error below.

The G/L impact of a transaction in a closed period cannot be changed.

The accounts getting impacted are active and nothing else has changed recently. Any idea what might be going wrong here? Can I use script to override this and take the bill off the hold?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those NetSuite quirks where a change to a transaction you would not think affects the G/L is considered to affect the G/L and so can't happen if the transaction is in a closed period.  Changing the payment hold must be one of those changes.  I know changing an address is as well, as well as changing Department/Class/Location.  Only option for these is to re-open the closed period (and therefore all closed periods between the posting period in question and now), make the change, then do your period closing process all over again for all the re-opened periods.